# How to Remove a sort duplicate in DatagridView Vb.NET?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, duplicates

[image: DatGridView]
**Hey Every One**,

I've problem in my datagridview which show some employes attendance (Entry time / leave time) with publication.

the problem is that some employees  mark his entrance many times  , so I've a file with many duplicates in time values (IN/OUT)

**Example :**

**1st** line an employee mark his entrance 3 times so I've to eliminate the 2 others and the last value of time must take theirs place

**3rd** line( in blue) I've some duplicate but not in the same order , so the value must be sort but time value also

Comment: How is the data getting into the grid in the first place?  It seems to me that the logical thing to do would be to prevent the creation of duplicates in the first place rather than trying to clear them out after the fact.

Comment: It's getting the data from .csv file
this is a simple line thant it was inserted :
"20133","01/06/2014","07:35:46","08:11:38","14:37:45","16:17:55","14:37:45",""

Comment: In that case, as I said, this really has nothing to do with the `DataGridView`. You should be processing the data before you even add it to the grid. You'll be reading the times in pairs for each record so, if the time in for one pair is the same as the time out for the previous pair then, instead of adding the new pair, just replace the time out of the previous pair.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late response, but I hope it answers your question:

It needs to be done *before* displaying a grid.

You need to go through whatever data source you're storing it in (or just parse your CSV file and store it in a string array) and run some sort of For-each loop, parsing each line/string, storing the current value, and the next, then comparing the two and iteratively shifting the data back to previously stored indexes. This would get a little tricky with storing previous/current/next values, indexes, etc., but it's required for doing what you want.

Alternatively, you could nip this in the bud and modify whatever program is storing these values in the first place and ignore clock-ins and clock-outs if the previous stored value is the same.